# Error 404 Not found - validate.js - When trying to use dmodel

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying to use the new dmodel module, but am unable to due to a 404 not found error.  Seems the jsonSchema module is referencing a module that does not exist in the package

'json-schema/lib/validate'

There is no such path or javascript file as far as I can tell in the dmodel package

My code looks like this

```
<script>
    require(
        [
        'dojo/_base/declare',
        'dstore/Memory',
        'dmodel/extensions/jsonSchema'
        ], 
    function (declare, Memory, jsonSchema) {
        var myStore = new Memory({

            model: jsonSchema({
                properties: {
                    someProperty: {
                        type: "number",
                        minimum: 0,
                        maximum: 10
                    },
                }
            })
        });


    });
</script>
```

And results in the 404 not found for this path

http://localhost:49294/json-schema/lib/validate.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation they mentions about the **JSON Schema (v3)** has been used.

It means you would need to include the json-schema package in you application. Unfortunately there is no mention about which package to use. In the package.json file, there is another mention about json-schema.

```
"devDependencies": {
     "intern-geezer": "1.6.*",
     "dstore": "1.0.0",
     "json-schema": "0.2.2"
   },
```

There are many version of the packages available, you should be able to use any one of them. more details here http://json-schema.org/implementations.html

You could probably use this https://github.com/kriszyp/json-schema. Its by the same contributor who has developed dmodel package.

Hope this was helpful.